# Unity Android: detect that a new update has ocurred

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, auto-update

Is it possible to automatically detect that a new version has been automatically installed to make some maintenance work?

Right now what I'm thinking is to compare the bundle version against I version database but I think is too much work

I was wondering if there was an easy way

Regards